# PHP / MYSQL Loop only iterates once, fails to store data in array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have the following piece of code which joins two tables and then returns all those users from `users` table who are teachers.

The users who qualifies to be teachers, information is then retrieved from the `teachers` table

So assuming there are 3 users who qualifies as teachers from the `users` table, all 3 those users with there information should be stored in an array.

The array gets empties when page loads

**SQL STATEMENT**

```
//IF my reasoning is correct the folllowing sql query should select alll users who qualifies as teachers
$sql = "SELECT users.*, teachers.*
        FROM users INNER JOIN teachers ON teachers.userID = users.userID";
```

**FUNCTION**

```
public function showAllTeachers()
    {
        $db = DB::getInstance();
        $sql = "SELECT users.*, teachers.*
        FROM users INNER JOIN teachers ON teachers.userID = users.userID";

        //simple DB QUERY
        $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmnt->execute();
        $teachers = $stmnt->fetchAll();
        $teacherInfo = array();

        //Check if there are any users who qualifies as teachers else return fals
        if ($stmnt->rowCount() > 0) {
            foreach($teachers as $teacher){
          //Store all teacher info in array $teacherInfo
          //There are more than 1 teacher so loop shouldl iterate more than once

                $teacherInfo = array('name' =>$teacher['firstname'], 'headline' =>$teacher['headline'], 'location' => $teacher['location'],
                    'age' => $teacher['age'], 'experience' => $teacher['experience'], 'imgPath' => $teacher['imgPath']);
            }//foreach

            //return array with teacher info
            return $teacherInfo;
        }//rowcount
        else {
            return false; //no teachers
                }
    }//function
```

Since there are more than 1 user who qualifies as a teacher `$teacherInfo` should now contain data for all those teachers

**Emptying Array**

The following runs when page is loaded and should display all teachers.

**My Problem**
When emptying array `$allTeachers`I only get one result (teacher) back. Thus my loop is only iterating once for some reason

```
 $teachers = new TeacherSearch();
           $allTeachers = $teachers->showAllTeachers();
            if(is_array($allTeachers)){
                foreach($allTeachers as $key => $teacher){
                    echo $key;
                    echo $teacher;
                    echo '<br />';
                }
              }
```

Any help much appreciated

**Additional Info**

Database

[image]

Teachers Table

[image]

Users Table

[image]

Users Table Data

[image]

Comment: $teacherInfo = array(...) <= you reinitialize your value in each loop ;)

Comment: @PierreGranger Actually, `$teacherInfo = array();` is outside of the loop, hence `$teacherInfo` is initialized once only (which is the desired behaviour). The problem comes from the missing brackets after `$teacherInfo`  in the statement `$teacherInfo = array('name'.....`, which overwrites the variable instead of appending an array to it.

Comment: I'm talking about the one in the loop, the $teacherInfo = array('name'...), not the one before the loop.

Comment: Right, I guess I misunderstood your comment, sorry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be a problem of your loop executing once only, add `echo 'test'` inside it, and you'll see it is executed multiple times (as long as `$teachers` has more than one element, of course).

The problem is you're overwriting `$teacherInfo` on each of your `foreach` loop execution, instead of appending a new array to it.

Replace :

```
$teacherInfo = array('name' =>$teacher['firstname'], 'headline' =>$teacher['headline'], 'location' => $teacher['location'],
    'age' => $teacher['age'], 'experience' => $teacher['experience'], 'imgPath' => $teacher['imgPath']);
```

With :

```
$teacherInfo[] = array('name' =>$teacher['firstname'], 'headline' =>$teacher['headline'], 'location' => $teacher['location'],
    'age' => $teacher['age'], 'experience' => $teacher['experience'], 'imgPath' => $teacher['imgPath']);
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer, the problem I am having now is that I get an `Array to String Conversion Error` when adding the advised `[]` brackets

Comment: The error occurs here `$allTeachers = $teachers->showAllTeachers();` When I do a `print_r` it shows the array with all correct values` However when I try to loop with `$allTeachers` I get above mentioned error

Comment: The `Array to String Conversion Error` comes from your `echo $teacher;` in your second script. `$teacher` is an array, you need to implode it or loop through it.